# Using Django/Postgres get a calculated field which get a field value if exist if not another field value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a Django Model:

```
Item(models.Model):

    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    alt_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to do a select in the database to get a new variable which will have the value of url if url exist, if not get the value of alt url

In pseudo-code:

```
'SELECT url=(url if url exist else alt_url) from item'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with "non-existing" you mean `NULL`, you can use the [**`Coalesce`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Item.objects.annotate(
    merge_url=Coalesce('url', 'alt_url')
)
```

Here the `Item`s will have an extra attribute `.merge_url` that contains the value of `url`, or if that does not exists, the value of `alt_url`.

That being said, for a case that is quite simple, it might be better to add a property to your model:

```
Item(models.Model):

    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    alt_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def merge_url(self):
        return self.url or self.alt_url
```

or if you are only interested in these values, you can write it like:

```
Item.objects.annotate(
    merge_url=Coalesce('url', 'alt_url')
).values_list('merge_url', flat=True)
```

Comment: what if it can be NULL or empty ?